# How do I use typedef as part of the base type of a declaration?

Tags: c++

Chapter 2.5 of the book C++ Primer says the following:

> The keyword *typedef* may appear as part of the base type of a declaration. Declarations that include *typedef* define type aliases rather than variables. As in any other declaration, the declarators can include type modifiers that define compound types built from the base type of the definition.

I know I can define a type alias as follows:

```
typedef int integer, & reference, * pointer;
```

but is this the kind of declaration the author means, or am I missing something here?

Comment: "I know I can define a type alias as follows" - you can, but don't.

Comment: To answer your questions: Yes. No.

Comment: FWIW I would use `using integer = int; using reference = integer&; using pointer = integer*;`.  A little more typing, but much clearer on intent.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> typedef int integer, & reference, * pointer;
> ```
>
> is this the kind of declaration the author means

Most likely not. Putting more than one `typedef` in a single statement does not mean they become compound types.

```
typedef int a, b;
```

still uses the simple type `int` to define two `typedef`s.

Examples of use of compound types to defined `typedef`s, regardless of whether they are defined in one statement or multiple statements:

```
typedef int& reference;
typedef int* pointer;
typedef int array[10];
```

Comment: Or probably more about things like `typedef const int ConstInt;`